# Namespaces without webservice

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Well, like the title says, I try to implement namespaces into a java xml class (meaning it gets some info and turns it into an xml) and have the problem that it should say "Artikel" and not "Artikel2", I tried using namespaces in my package info:

```
@XmlSchema( 
    namespace = "", 
elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package camelpack2;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

and have the namespace in artikel2

```
@XmlType(namespace =" ", name = "Artikel",propOrder = {
    "Artikel",
    })
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", crlf = "UNIX", skipFirstLine = false)
@Link
public class Artikel2 {
@XmlElement(namespace=" ",required = false, name = "Artikel")
protected List<Artikel2> Artikel;
```

but in my bindy I have to link to the Artikel2 class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Poste", propOrder = { "Adresse", "Artikel", "Artikel2" })
@CsvRecord(separator = ",", crlf = "UNIX", skipFirstLine = false)
public class Poste {

@Link
private Adresse Adresse;
@Link 
private Artikel Artikel;
@Link
private Artikel2 Artikel2;
```

so it will always give out Artikel2 no matter what I do and in addition to that it sets all the nodes in Artikel2 to `<ns2: Nodename>`.

tl;dr: don't know how to use namespace when not using some kind of webservice like Blaise described(http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html), jaxb.properties doesn't work.

Comment: If you want to use namespaces, why are all your namespaces blank? A namespace should be a URL. --- The `@XmlType` will affect an XML Schema (`.xsd` file). It won't affect the generated XML. --- What is the `@Link` annotation? Seems irrelevant whatever it is. --- To control the generate XML element name, use `@XmlElement`

Comment: Perhaps you can manage to produce a complete, verifyable set of code. These incoherent snippets of code make it hard to see where your problem is. References ("as Blaise described") should be backed up by a link.

Comment: @ link links to the class so the artikel class will be in the poste class it's a bindy anotation.. Also fixed the code, maybe it's easier to understand now

Comment: also the empty namespace isnt the problem, its not as if it would refer to the page in the namespace, you can write "www.idontgetthisatall.com"and still it would work, ven if the website doesnt exist.. i want to use namespace to get Artikel 2 to Artikel. and have to refer to any namespace at all to do so.

Comment: the problem is: the namespace works fine, but the @link annotation reverses it again, so it's artikel2 artikel2 :/ cant write artikel 2 times for obvious reasons and ant get a processor to work with the outgoing message...